# Trivial knot with some crossing points

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Suppose $K$ is a knot diagram of a trivial knot with some crossing points. Then we know that there is a finite sequence of Reidemeister moves to transform $K$ to a trivial diagram (diagram with no crossings). Now I’m asking about the sequence ? Is there an example of such $K$ such that the Reidemeister moves which increase the number of crossing points must be involved in any sequence transforming $K$ to trivial? In other words, can we say that any sequence to eliminate the crossing points does not involve creation of crossing points? I know this is not true in general ( transform a diagram to a diagram with minimal number of crossings) but I wonder if it’s true for trivial diagram

Answer (score 1):

There is a diagram of the unknot such that any sequence of Reidemeister moves transforming the diagram into the standard diagram must increase the number of crossings. Here is an example due to [Kauffman and Lambropoulou](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/IntellUnKnot.pdf):
[image]

One can prove that the number of crossings must increase in any sequence by performing all available Reidemeister 3 moves and observing that there are no Reidemeister 1 or 2 moves available that decrease the number of crossings. An unknotting sequence for the diagram is below (also taken from the paper of Kauffman and Lambropoulou).[image]

See this related discussion on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53471/are-there-any-very-hard-unknots).